# XcodeKit and SourceKit

Tags: sourcekit, xcodekit

I don't have experience in XcodeKit and SourceKit apart from a few articles that I read and the official pages 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit#topics
https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/SourceKit

I'm trying to understand the differences between the two and what they are capable of doing exactly.

I think XcodeKit essentially let you add commands to Xcode menu and makes it possible to interact with the source code you have open by creating an app extension which you can then also distribute through the App Store.
As far as I could understand XcodeKit only let you get information from the current focused file (not all the files in project), then you can get selected text etc... At least that's what I read until Xcode 9, not sure if things are better now.

SourceKit also interacts with source code but looks like more powerful but more low level.

What I'm wondering is:

- Does SourceKit make it possible to access to all the Swift and ObjC classes that you have in your open project, and then extract informations out of it? 
  For example let's say that I want to extract informations like structs and classes, methods of each class, and then generate some sort of output out of it.
  How do I use SourceKit (or XcodeKit?) to do that?
- Any link to examples would be great!
- Is SourceKit still actual and supported by Apple?

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/tools/SourceKit/docs/Protocol.md

Thanks

Comment: I found this which looks very interesting and also more easy to use with Swift: https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on your end goal, you have a few options:

- `SwiftSyntax` is a new (beta) open-source framework from Apple for walking through/modifying a document’s AST (abstract syntax tree). More information & an example are available on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax).
- As mentioned, [`SourceKitten`](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) is a Swift library for communicating with [`SourceKit`](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/SourceKit). `SourceKit` is the backbone of Xcode, which is really just a glorified text editor without it. It provides everything from semantically-analyzed substructures and generated interfaces to code-completion and syntax highlighting—everything an IDE needs. It is the most encompassing option and it's not going anywhere anytime soon (as [Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987497) mentioned, Apple's even developing a [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) interface for it.) *Shameless plug*: I’ve further developed [`Sylvester`](https://github.com/chriszielinski/Sylvester) , a typed, XPC-available `SourceKitten` (`SourceKit`) interface with some sugar. The `SKEditorOpen` request should provide you with enough information to extract whatever you want from a source document.
- [`XcodeKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit) exposes an extremely limited API to interacting with the source code. In fact, it only provides a mutable buffer of the open document in the editor that the user invoked the command from.

As for your inquiry on retrieving the currently open documents in the editor, your only option would be to use the <s>wonderful</s> scripting interface that Xcode exposes. The Xcode SDEF file can be found at */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Xcode.sdef*. You can use the [`ScriptingBridge`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scriptingbridge) framework to do so from a Cocoa application. If you're using Swift, then the [`SwiftScripting`](https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting) repository is crucially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct, XcodeKit allows interaction with the editor window and (selected) text in it, and SourceKit has the knowledge of the programming language syntax. AFAIK, SourceKit is very much alive and the next big thing will be LSP - https://github.com/apple/sourcekit-lsp